# Logar automaticamente em um web-site c# Programaticamente

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webrequest

A empresa em que trabalho possui 3 websites  ambos com login e senha

Gostaria de saber algo em c# .NET ou em Javascript que seja a partir de um link redirecione logado.

1 Passo:  Acessar o Site 1 www.site.com.br 
2 Passo:  Fazer Login Site 1
3 Passo:  Dentro do Site 1 (SiteA SiteB SiteC)  ao clicar em qualquer um redirecionar logado - e não precisar logar novamente.

O objetivo é centralizar em 1 único site, e dentro dele estar os 3 sites.

Consegui fazer isso no windows form  seguindo este video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=baA2tph_yTo

```
navigate("http://www.seusite.com.br/login.aspx");
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_login").InnerText = textBox1.Text.ToString();
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_pass").InnerText = textBox2.Text.ToString();
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_sent").InvokeMember("click");
```

Porém na Web não encontrei uma grande ajuda.

Comment: Precisamos de mais algumas informações: os 3 sites são sub-domínios de um mesmo domínio? Estão no mesmo servidor? Como a sessão é mantida em cada um deles (cookie ou outo método)? Você possui acesso aos fontes/bando de dados? É possível fazer, mas pode ser bem complicado, de acordo com as respostas a estas perguntas.

Comment: Você pode implementar SSO (Single Sign On) nos sites ou OpenAuth para que todos eles compartilhem o token de autenticação, mas isso exige muita implementação

Comment: Você está utilizando autenticação com AD (Active Directory)?

Comment: Acredito que você tenha um sistema de logon home-brewed, neste caso já que você quer compartilhar o logon entre domínios diferentes, então uma saída seria implementar uma WebAPI (novo domínio) de para realizar o logon, este poderia retornar um Token que faria o logon automático no sistema atual.

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira São domínios diferentes em outro servidor... os 3 são em cookies ... Não possuo acesso ao código fonte... pois é o pessoal da nossa matriz no EUA que faz a manutenção ... Mas possuo o acesso de administrador que é possível criar login nos 3 sites. Por exemplo : um vendedor X usa o mesmo nome de usuário e senha nos 3 diferentes.sites Eu montei um banco de dados sqlserver... onde armazeno o usuário e senha dos vendedores

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira No site principal da empresa do Brasil eu tenho acesso ao código fonte e fomos nós q desenvolvemos... nele quero criar um novo login O usuário vai loga armazena em cookie por exemplo e ao clicar em um dos 3 site ...ele inserir a o usuário e senha e depois dá um submit tudo automaticamente

Comment: @JuniorPedro Utilizando uma chamada Ajax a cada um dos domínios enviando a informação de login deve ser possível. É necessário configurar o servidor para permitir chamadas Ajax de origens diferentes, e configurar o cookie gerado corretamente (ele deve ser utiizado não apenas em requisições HTTP simples). Em PHP e JS são todas tarefas simples de serem realizadas, mas pode não ser possível já que você não possui acesso ao código fonte. Posso dar mais detalhes, se a "solução" (gambiarra) interessar. Mas o correto, seria fazer essa troca de sessões no backend.

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira Dependendo do que eu tenho que fazer no código fonte dos terceiros eu posso solicitar para fazer, acredito que seria ideal no backend porém no futuro vai unificar tudo.. nao vejo problemas no front.. igual do video em que postei, poderia postar esta solução em ajax para eu analisar como funciona ?.Obrigado.

Comment: @TobyMosque Como seria este webAPI ?

Comment: @Caputo Montei um teste usando o SSO  para validar um token porém como eu nao tenho acesso ao codigo fonte de 1 dos sites não consigo fazeno-lo alguma sugestão ?

Comment: A função que faz login é publicada? Se for, você pode realizar o login no 3 site via API

Comment: @Caputo é sim,, porem está escuro pra mim sobre o API

Comment: E eles não podem te dar suporte ou fornecer a documentação da API?